# Delete Row if it includes two input values

Tags: vba, for-loop, delete-row, inputbox

I need to search a list for two input values that you define via pop up window. the inputs work but the for/if loop won't start and I'm stumped. Any help is appreciated.

Code Below:

```
Dim dieNumber As Variant
Dim serial As Variant
Dim i As Long


Set rng = Range("A3:J1000") 'range of master list

dieNumber = InputBox("Enter Die Number to Delete")
serial = InputBox("Enter Serial Number of Die")

With ActiveSheet

For i = 1000 To Rows.Count

    If (Row.Cells(2).Value = dieNumber And Row.Cells(3).Value = serial) Then

        EntireRow.Delete

    End If

Next i

End With
```

Comment: You are intending to start at row 1000 right?

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
Dim dieNumber As Variant
Dim serial As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

Set rng = ws.Range("A3:J1000") 'range of master list

dieNumber = InputBox("Enter Die Number to Delete")
serial = InputBox("Enter Serial Number of Die")

For i = 1000 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
    If ws.Range("B", & i).Value = dieNumber And ws.Range("C", & i).Value = serial Then
        ws.Range("B", & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

But if you are trying to delete the items from the range you will want to change your for loop to start at 3.

```
For i = 3 To
```

Comment: I changed the code to that but it isn't deleting it. Running without any errors but the excel sheet isn't changing. Any idea why? and I used the I=3 as I'm trying to delete from the range. Was trying to start from the bottom but I guess I never changed it back. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: I'm not sure what condition your worksheet state is in when the code is being run so i will change it to specifically work on the sheet you want. See change to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Rand = 3 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

If Cells(Rand, 2).Value = DieNumber And Cells(Rand, 3).Value = Serial Then
        Rows(Rand).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

This is what ended up working for me. Thanks for your help MatthewD